# Group MySQL into buckets based on table Max / Min

Tags: mysql

I am writing an MySQL query that will take a table, split it into buckets of equal size of a given column, and then return a count of values within each bucket. This isnt the same as 10 equal "count" buckets - I am expecting the number of records in each bucket to vary - but for them to be split equally by a given column.

I have data as follows:

```
User   | Followers
----------------
User 1 | 100
User 2 | 1000
User 3 | 1300
User 4 | 2000
User 5 | 10000
```

I would like to split the data into 5 equal sized "follower" buckets - ie buckets of increasing 2000 followers. So there would be an output as follows:

```
Bucket          | Count
-----------------------
1.(0 - 2000)    | 3
2.(2000 - 4000) | 1
3.(4000 - 6000) | 0
4.(6000 - 8000) | 0
4.(8000 - 10000)| 1
```

So far I've tried the following:

```
SELECT (followers)%(bucket_size),COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT (ROUND((MAX(followers)/MIN(followers))/10,0)) as bucket_size FROM users
WHERE followers > 0) as a
INNER JOIN users
GROUP BY (followers)%(bucket_size)
```

But this is providing me with all distinct values.

Comment: I do not understand your question. You want to divide users on the basis of follower count. No matter how many followers user has. You want to divide them in 5 equal range. Is that it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation as follows:

```
select 1 + (t.followers - 1) %  b.bucket_size bucket, count(*) no_users
from mytable t
cross join (select 2000 bucket_size) b
group by t.followers %  b.bucket_size
```

On the other hand, if you want to also return empty buckets, as shown in your desired results, it is a bit different. You can use an inline query to list the buckets, then bring the table with a `left join`:

```
select n bucket, count(t.followers) cnt
from (select 2000 bucket_size) b
cross join (select 1 bucket union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5) n
left join mytable t on (t.followers - 1) %  b.bucket_size = n.bucket - 1
group by n.bucket
```

Comment: "You can use aggregation as follows" What is aggregation? I know about aggregate functions.

Comment: @Aman: aggregation refers to queries with a `group by` clause, and/or that use aggregate functions, such as `count()`, `sum()`, `avg()`.

Comment: So the solution I am looking for would be dynamic - so when we add more users the buckets still split into equal sizes - ie if a user comes in with 100,000 followers, the new buckets would be 20,000 in size.

Comment: By bucket O.P. means range user who has 0-20000 followers.

Answer (score 0):

If having empty buckets is not important, here is a simple and readable solution:

```
select  bucket as Bucket, 
        count(*) as Count
from (
    select  case when followers between 0 and 1999 then '(0-2000)'
                 when followers between 2000 and 3999 then '(2000-4000)'
                 when followers between 4000 and 5999 then '(4000-6000)'
                 when followers between 6000 and 7999 then '(6000-8000)'
                 when followers between 8000 and 10000 then '(8000-10000)'
             end as bucket
    from users
) buckets 
group by bucket
```

You can also play around with the above query here: [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kC7RFxJ3h6Mhd8E7BeQeBV/2)

Comment: So the solution I am looking for would be dynamic - so when we add more users the buckets still split into equal sizes - ie if a user comes in with 100,000 followers, the new buckets would be 20,000 in size.